# alternative to jqgrid triggerToolbar on a local dataset

Tags: jqgrid, filter, local, reload

I have a jqgrid displaying a large amount data. The data is retrieved from the server periodically via a jquery ajax call (outside of the jqgrid logic). The retrieved data is compared to the data previously retried ( and stored as a var in js. it is served as the data for the jqgrid). if they are different the local data is refreshed, then trigger the jqgrid to reload. the jqgrid datatype is jsonstring.

This solution is working quite well, except when the user have a filter value in the filter toolbar. because i set a timer for 0.1 sec to trigger filter in the loadcomplete event, the whole grid refresh when there is a filter string looks like this:

- 20 records were displayed in the jqgrid originally (because the user is filtering on a certain value in a column)
- jqgrid is refreshed, because the data polled from the server by the separated ajax call is different than the one stored in the browser
- jqgrid will show all the new data for a very short period of time
- jqgrid filter is triggered within loadcomplete. and the screen is showing 20 records again.

it is technically still working. but is there a way to re-apply the filter locally on the jsonstring before the grid is visualised? put in a different way, can the jqgrid to visualise only once, which will both load the new jsonsting and apply the filter that was placed in the filter box before at the same time?

thanks
casbby

update:

I have tried one of Oleg's solution to apply filter while reloading the grid. this is [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridFiltered.htm). it worked perfectly as long as the the datatype is local. my page actually use the datatype jsonstring to reload the grid. This function from the code does seem to apply to jsonstring. i was hoping to call such a function after a external jquery ajax successfully retrieved the data form the server.

```
function filter() {
            var searchFiler = $("#filter").val(), f;

            if (searchFiler.length === 0) {
                grid[0].p.search = false;
                $.extend(grid[0].p.postData,{filters:""});
            }
            f = {groupOp:"OR",rules:[]};
            f.rules.push({field:"name",op:"cn",data:searchFiler});
            f.rules.push({field:"note",op:"cn",data:searchFiler});
            grid[0].p.search = true;
            $.extend(grid[0].p.postData,{filters:JSON.stringify(f)});
            grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1,current:true}]);
        }
```

can someone please help me out? many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are small differences in the usage of `datatype: "jsonstring"` in comparing with the usage of `datatype: "local"`. You can compare the corresponding parts of the code [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.base.js#L1856-1879). One from the differences in the code of `datatype: "local"` is the usage of `addLocalData` and `populateVisible` functions. The last function (`populateVisible`) will be used only in case of virtual scrolling (`scroll: 1` or `scroll: true`). In your case important difference between `datatype: "jsonstring"` and `datatype: "local"` is the call of `addLocalData` in case of `datatype: "local"`.

The function `addLocalData` apply grouping and filtering of local data (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.base.js#L1599-1609)). Moreover it cut the list of displayed rows to the current page (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.1/js/grid.base.js#L1628)).

So if the server returns unfiltered data and you need display filtered data then you should use `datatype: "local"` instead of `datatype: "jsonstring"`. Instead of `datastr` you should use `data`. You can need to use `localReader` instead of `jsonReader` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#array_data)) or just convert manually the data returned from the server to the format which could be read by default `localReader`.

**UPDATE**: In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13081756/315935) I described and included the demo which shows how `localReader` can be used.

What you can alternatively do is to convert your input data returned from the server to the standard format (or return the data from the server in the format). The `data` parameter should be array of named objects with properties like the column names in `colMode`. So what you can do is just a simple loop through `rows` array and creating another array in the format which jqGrid required. The corresponding code could be about the following:

```js
// let us you have myImput with myImput.rows
// and you have cm which you use as the value of colModel parameter
var mydata = [], input = myImput.rows, l = input.length,
    cmLength = cm.length, i, j, inputItem, item;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    inputItem = input[i];
    item = {id: inputItem.id};
    inputItem = inputItem.cell;
    for (j = 0; j < cmLength; j++) {
        item[cm[j].name] = inputItem[j];
    }
    mydata.push(item);
}
```

After such conversion you can use `mydata` array as the value of `data` parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I have to admit. Tony has done a great job to create the jqgrid but I learned more about jqgrid from reading your post.

Comment: i have been trying to use datatype local to process the data polled from the server, but the grid always renders blank. i can not think how can the default localreader in document will work. in all the dataype local examples, i can only see an array containing arrays of column field values. but the default localReader requires the format {root: "rows", page: "page",total: "total", records: "records", repeatitems: false, cell: "cell", id: "id"} . which is the same as the jsonreader except the repeattimes. am i missing something?

Comment: @casbby: Is it not easy to post the example of the data which the server returns? Including the code which defines jqGrid can clear other opened questions. If I would guess you can try with `datatype: "local", data: mydata, localReader: {repeatitems: false}` instead of `datatype: "jsonstring", datastr: mydata`

Comment: i had a look of the addlocadata function from the source code, it looks like

Comment: yeah, defintely. my data polled from the server roughly like this '{
        "page":"1",
        "total":1,
        "records":"1",
        "rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["v1","v2","v3","v4"]},
                {"id":"2","cell":["v1","v2","v3","v4"]}],
}'. i had a look the addlocaldata function from the source code.the very first thing it does is ' if(!$.isArray(ts.p.data)) {
return;
}' so mydata can not be a json object, it has to be an array. if i am assigning the json returned from the server to mydata, i have to use data:mydata.rows to make it work?  (i have not got chance to prove it)

Comment: @casbby: I haven't seen your last comment before I have read [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/jqgrid-using-datatypelocal-to-read-a-json-string-with-customised-localreader/#p27629). Sometime notifications works not in stackoverflow. I wrote **UPDATED** part in my answer where I described a possible workaround. It would be probably better if you change the format of data returned from the server. You should return *all data* from the server independent from the requested page. I think you have currently also always `"page":"1", "total":1, "records":"1"`