# Jqgrid datatype local loading from array

Tags: jqgrid

During my question about how to re-apply the toolbar filter after the underline data is refreshed from a local js var question [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12983215/alternative-to-jqgrid-triggertoolbar-on-a-local-dataset), Oleg has provided me an solution:
1 use the combination of datatype:"local" and data:localvar.

Now I am facing a different problem which after a week I was not able to solve.

According to the Jqgrid wiki when using local datasource the default localreader looks like

```
The initial configuration of the localReader is the same as those from jsonReader

localReader = {
   root: "rows",
   page: "page",
   total: "total",
   records: "records",
   repeatitems: false,
   cell: "cell",
   id: "id",
   userdata: "userdata",
   subgrid: {root:"rows", repeatitems: true, cell:"cell"}
}
```

I found this is not the case. Because in every examples that i can find using dataype:"local", it always uses a straight js array in stead of an js object, looking like this:

```
var mydata = [       
{id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},   
   {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, 
{id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}];
```

I have tried using the default localReader (with repeatitems set to true) to process

```
var locObj = {"rows":[
       {"id":0,"cell":["val1","val2","val3"]},
       {"id":1,"cell":["val1","val2","val3"]}
        ],
  "page":"1",
  "total":"1",
  "records":"2"
}
```

with 
     datatype:"local",
     data:locObj

this will not work, because it wont pass the array check in the addlocaldata function. if I change the option to be 
     datatype:"local",
     data:locObj.rows

I got a grid with correct number of rows but each cell has an empty value. I think that is becasue the addlocaldata function can not handle an array formatted like locObj.rows.

is there a way to actually process a json object (or string) with the datatype:"local" using the customised localreader (in stead of having to re-create an array on the client side)?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Casbby

Answer (score 5):

What you need to do is just the usage of

```js
data: locObj.rows,
localReader: {repeatitems: true}
```

See [the corresponding demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalReader.htm).

Comment: @PavelDmitrenko: The information is the part of question: datatype local loading from array. By the way, the fork [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), which I develop, don't required `datatype: 'local'` if `data` parameter is specified. See examples [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html)